# What is the best way to use an id with an entity

Tags: java, hibernate, domain-driven-design

What is the best way to use id with entity in Domain Drive Design and with Hibernate? For example there is an Rest api with method to get user by id from a database. An user gives an id, e.g 1 and he this he is getting a first user but gets an error despite the fact that there are severals users in a db because earlier an user with id 1 was deleted and there are e.g three users with id 2,3 and 4. You know, this is a problem with autoincremental id from Hibernate entity and i search this problem solution.

Comment: It's not clear at all what your problem actually is.   Could you try to ask again with more detail?

Comment: ID is an identifier, not a position in some ever changing List or collection. Think of using your full name as an identifier and it'll make more sense why, when deleting an entry with id 'Sampeteq', you don't get anything when searching for that record after. That you use DB assigned numerical sequencing is an implementation detail; one that makes it easier to just keeping going forward instead of trying to cycle back and reuse ones from deleted rows (which would have its own consequences to the application)

Answer (score 1):

In this case the id is an internal concern and the user shouldn't be fetching something by id anyway.

If it is not the user fetching by id, but an internal service call, then you should look into using pessimistic locking with JPA to make sure that after your first call to look up the id is done, the record does not get deleted by another user.

You can also consider using foreign keys if it fits your use case.